# Silverstripe Menu, Submenu, and Breadcrumbs

Tags: menu, submenu, silverstripe, breadcrumbs

How do I change the default Silverstripe theme 'Simple' so that when a submenu (on the sidebar) is clicked the sidebar menu is replaced by a breadcrumb via $Breadcrumbs. Example when Menu1 is clicked, the sidebar is shown

```
       Menu1   Menu2    Menu3
```

Menu1 (not clickable, just a title)
  SubMenu1
  SubMenu2

but when either SubMenu1 or SubMenu2 is clicked entire sidebar dissapears and a $Breadcrumbs is shown.

```
       Menu1   Menu2    Menu3
```

Menu1-->SubMenu1
        $Content

Therefore when Menu1 on Breadcrumb is clicked, it goes back to Menu1.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you want to achieve this? I can't see a real benefit out here, but if you really need this, so this could be possible an answer:

1) If you are on the `$Menu(1)` level show only `$MenuTitle.XML` (or just `$Title`, they're almost the same)in the sidebar

2) Else If you are on the `$Menu(2)` or deeper than `(2)` level show breadcrumbs

You could achieve this by checking on which level you are at the moment and display what you need:

```
<% if $Menu(1) %>
  <!-- Here you print only titles-->
  <% loop $Menu(1) %>
    <a href="$Link">$MenuTitle.XML</a>
  <% end_loop %>
<% else %>
  <!-- Here you print out the BreadCrumbs, only if you are deeper than 1st level menu -->
  <% include $BreadCrumbs %>
<% end_if %>
```

Here you check if you are on **first level** then display only titles with links, then if you are on the **subpage** display the `BreadCrumbs`