# SilverStripe 3 and breadcrumbs

Tags: templates, silverstripe, breadcrumbs

Like the subject in this question:
[Silverstripe Menu, Submenu, and Breadcrumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275284/silverstripe-menu-submenu-and-breadcrumbs)

I would like to change the normal breadcrumbs into something else. Normally, the Simple theme puts breadcrumbs in the side panel. I want to change that method and create a Wordpress style set of breadcrumbs on the subject line.

There is a pretty nice set of breadcrumbs in the footer. That may be somewhat redundant but users are used to seeing the Wordpress style so that is the task.

It is clear from the docs how to change the separator character but it is not so clear how to change the page template to have the breadcrumbs in the page content and not a separate set in the sidebar.

Is there a simple way to do this in the Page.ss template?

Example:

```
MainMenuHome  menu1 menu2
                    menu3

      home >> menu1 >> menu2 >> menu3
      Page subject menu3

      Page Content

Footer
  Sitename -> home / menu1 / menu2
```

Answer (score 5):

Breadcrumbs are called into the template with the `$Breadcrumbs` variable (see *SiteTree.php*).

To change the look and feel of the breadcrumbs, you can override the *BreadcrumbsTemplate.s*s file in your theme.

Comment: I understand that. But HOW do I do that.

Comment: Just copy cms/templates/BreadcrumbsTemplate to your theme Includes/ directory and modify it as you see fit.